# Prompt in Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm implementing an app using JavaScript and I have a problem with the command "Prompt". 
In Android it works fine but in Windows Phone 8 it doesn't work at all.

Example:

```
var person = prompt("Please enter your name");

if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer blocks the `prompt` method in IE7+ for security reasons. You will have to roll your own instead.

Comment: But Internet Explorer 11 Desktop on Windows 8.1 Pro, when loading a prepared `window.prompt` page (in Edge render mode) from my own IIS Express server, gives me a working prompt...

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of purposes there is a notification plugin in phonegap which also can be used as prompt

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

```
// Amazon Fire OS / Android / BlackBerry 10 (OS 5.0 and higher) / iOS / Tizen
//
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

Don't forget to see the quirk section to get it work in windows phone

Windows Phone 7 and 8 Quirks

> There is no built-in browser alert, but you can bind one as follows to
>   call alert() in the global scope:
>
> window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
>
> Both alert and confirm are non-blocking calls, results of which are
>   only available asynchronously.