# WP8 not show error when onFailure invoke http adapter hybrid Mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

This issue only on WP8 (Android, iOS, and BB10 is fine).

Sample code when call adapter :

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : appAdapterName,
    procedure : 'checkSignature',
    parameters : [arg0, arg1]
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess : checkSignatureSuccess,
    onFailure : checkSignatureFailure
});
```

Handle success :

```
function checkSignatureSuccess(result){
    alert("success");
}
```

Handle error :

```
function checkSignatureFailure(result){
        alert(result.errorCode);
    }
```

When i turn off my back-end service, on Android, iOS and BB10 can show alert "PROCEDURE_ERROR". But on WP8, not showing any alert.

This is log from message.log when my back-end service is down.

```
    response:
Not Found
Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type=text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length=1144
Date=Thu, 22 Sep 2016 11:22:05 GMT
<html><head><title>xxxxxxxx</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>xxxxxx: HTTP Status 404 - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>xxxxxx: type</b> xxxxxx: Status report</p><p><b>xxxxx: message</b> <u>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</u></p><p><b>xxxxxx: description</b> <u>xxxxxxxx: The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h3></body></html> [project xxxxx]
[9/22/16 18:20:00:102 ICT] 00000127 om.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl E FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project xxxxx]ApplicationHTTPAdapter/checkSignature:  parameters: [project xxxxx]
TypeError: Cannot read property "Body" from undefined (2016-09-22T17:04:18.759Z/6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b/ApplicationHTTPAdapter-impl.js#121)
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project xxxxx]nullorg.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "Body" from undefined (2016-09-22T17:04:18.759Z/6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b/ApplicationHTTPAdapter-impl.js#121)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2016_09_22T17_04_18_759Z_6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b_ApplicationHTTPAdapter_impl_js_3._c_sendRequest_5(2016-09-22T17:04:18.759Z/6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b/ApplicationHTTPAdapter-impl.js:121)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2016_09_22T17_04_18_759Z_6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b_ApplicationHTTPAdapter_impl_js_3._c_checkSignature_76(2016-09-22T17:04:18.759Z/6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b/ApplicationHTTPAdapter-impl.js:1785)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2016_09_22T17_04_18_759Z_6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b_ApplicationHTTPAdapter_impl_js_3.call(2016-09-22T17:04:18.759Z/6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b/ApplicationHTTPAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2016_09_22T17_04_18_759Z_6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b_ApplicationHTTPAdapter_impl_js_3.call(2016-09-22T17:04:18.759Z/6733847e906e1c3f58643f980a1375aa2209260b/ApplicationHTTPAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:267)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:241)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:211)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:775)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:721)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$200(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:74)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:603)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:600)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:160)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:178)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.service(GadgetAPIServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

                                 com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Comment: Can you try 

//////
function checkSignatureFailure(result){
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}
//////
just to see if any response is reaching the client.
Also, if you wait 30 seconds , do you see the error callback firing ? Just trying to see if it is waiting for the default timeout period of 30 seconds

Comment: Hai Vivin, thanks anyway for your response.
I was trying to use JSON.stringify(result) and still not receive any response.
I also wait until 30 seconds and not receive error code "REQUEST_TIMEOUT".
For a while, i use setTimeout javascript function for this condition and only for WP8 platform, until i found the solution for this case. Hehe.
Please tell me if you have any other suggestions. Thanks anyway Vivin.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone does not support display of the `alert` method. Instead you need to come up with a different way of displaying prompts to the end-user in your application.

For example, use this: [Prompt in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269836/prompt-in-windows-phone)

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);

function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Hai Idan, thanks anyway for your answer, but i think the problem is not about alert method. Because, if I turn on my back-end service again, WP8 can show alert "success". I try to change alert method with change page event jquery mobile, and WP8 still cannot read it.

Its look like WP8 not receive any response from WL.Client.invokeProcedure.